# 。。。を言います　。。。と言います？

Tags: particles

I've seen/heard both を言います and　と言いますof these used. What is the difference?

Comment: See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/what-is-the-difference-between-using-%E3%82%92-and-%E3%81%A8-with-the-verb-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86