# Function of と言う

Tags: translation

[image]

The context:The person who are saying these have been attacked and while he was running away got injured.Madoka finds him and she is trying to help him.

My question is:What's the function of と言う here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by istrasci [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/what-is-the-difference-between-using-%E3%82%92-and-%E3%81%A8-with-the-verb-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86), in this case と is a quotation marker (the use of brackets also hints at that). So it literally means:

> Say "run away without me".

Look closer, not all these options are about saying something. The third option is a different kind of action. So the brackets and と言う are used to make it clear what is a phrase and what isn't.